# ubuntu won't boot to recovery mode

Tags: boot, grub2, recovery-mode

I have installed nvidia driver this way and rebooted:

```
apt install nvidia-driver-460
```

After that Ubuntu won't boot. It shows blank screen and does not respond not any keys. Looks like something wrong with grub.

I have tried to boot to recovery mode but it hangs during boot. The last line that I see is:

```
[ OK ] Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes
```

Comment: Does an external keyboard respond?

Comment: Also, how long did you wait at that prompt? Something unknown may be an issue and that prompt may sit there for a bit. So, if you weren't patient then you might want to give it a little bit longer to see if you get past it.

Comment: I have fixed it by adding property linux  init=/bin/sh (I have edited grub file) then I reached a shell, remounted FS to read\write and uninstalled nvidia driver.